# API POST Call in VBA and parameters

Tags: excel, vba, api

I would like to send POST request with parameters et header to an API with Excel and VBA.

The curl is like :

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://api-url-mycompany.net/countries' \
--header 'x-api-key: 'TEST01KEY' \
--form 'continent="europe"'
```

In VBA, I've managed to send my API Key I found how to include one parameter 'area="europe"' to the code.

Please see below my VBA code:

```
Public Sub Area()

Dim XMLHTTP As New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60
Dim myurl As String
Dim result As String
Dim Test() As String


myurl = "https://api-url-mycompany.net/countries"
XMLHTTP.Open "POST", myurl, False

XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "x-api-key", "TEST01KEY"
XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
XMLHTTP.send "continent=europe"

RESPONSE = req.responseText

Range("A1").Value = RESPONSE

End Sub
```

But I'm not able to do the same with several parameters.
Imagine the curl is like :

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://api-url-mycompany.net/regions' \
--header 'x-api-key: TEST01KEY' \
--form 'continent="europe"' \
--form 'country="germany"'
```

Thanks for your help!

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Dim param As String
param = "area=" & Chr$(34) & "europe" & Chr$(34) ' Generates the string area="europe"
req.Open "POST", ReqURL, False
req.setRequestHeader "x-api-key", "TEST01KEY"
req.Send(param)
```